# How to hide ads on small screens

Tags: javascript, mobile, web, ads

I wish to hide one ad on mobile version of my site. I want to do it this way.

```
<script>
    if(screen.width > 900){
        "here call the script that is ad"
    }
</script>
```

my ad script is also js script but it is not on my domain so I can not use ajax call to call it. Any help is appreciated.
my ad code looks like

```
<script src='//url..'> </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just do that with css and media queries?

Wrap that add in a DIV (let's say `<div id="ad_1">...[link to your ad or content]...</div>`) and add to your stylesheet

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  #ad_1 { display: none; }
}
```

Comment: still, it has to be in some kind of wrapper div that usually has an ID or at least a class (use the browser developer tools to find out). Find that ID or class and add that CSS rule for it...